# Why is Ext.isReady returning false?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm updating my `extjs` from `4.2.1` to `5.1`.

I have successfully updated the `extjs` framework directory and all necessary paths in my application. But, I am running into a blank screen issue.

I have observed that the `launch()` and `init()` methods from Application.js never reach the debugger.

I have also checked:

```
Ext.isReady = false
Ext.isDomReady = true
```

What exactly is it that I'm missing? I can see that the `ext-all-debug` file is loaded, but why is `Ext.isReady` still set to false?

Comment: From where did you import the ext-all-debug.js file?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I import `ext-all-debug.js` from home.jsp file

Comment: I try for removing `controllers` from app.js and it works for Ext.isReady = true.why I'm not able to add my all controller in app.js file in `Extjs 5.1` ?

Comment: Finlay got problem in model convert property ...https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287985-Data-Field-Convert-DefaultValue-Interaction